# How to search for a file when 'find' is not an option

Tags: linux, bash, find

Is there a good way to search for a file if you are for ex. stuck in dracut/initrd?

The only thing that I was able to do was:
`ls /**/**/**/**/* | grep "file name"`

Answer (score 1):

`ls -R | grep filename` is a little cleaner, but without `find`, options are limited.